# What was the culture context for having close relationship between boss and workers in early 1900s Germany?

Tags: 20th-century, germany

I'm reading Die Verwandlung by Franz Kafka. In the beginning parts of it, the story involves the protagonist Gregor's manager visiting him a few times, to figure out why he wasn't coming to work (Gregor turned into a giant insect). I found the closeness of the employee-boss relationship quite interesting.

So, my question is, what was the culture context for having such close relationship of boss and workers during that time?

This type of arrangement is quite unthinkable for me, because these days, I think it is often emphasized to separate work life and private life in Germany.

Comment: I don't one can find about this topic easily using a google search @MCW. Also, I have mentioned a current culture, which indicates why this q is important.

Comment: It wasn't common in Germany, or elsewhere in central Europe, for an employee to turn into a giant insect. So it is certainly possible that the manager behaved atypically too, if Kafka felt it contributed to the story.

Comment: @davidlol - any references for that assertion??? This is History SE after all…

Comment: I don't think it would be that unusual anywhere in the present day for a manager to call or text a previously-reliable employee who stopped coming to work, which is the equivalent of what Gregor's manager was doing then.

Comment: ahahhahahaa lol @JonCuster

Comment: Inverse question: how did North America in particular and Western nations in general develop such stark professional boundaries over the last 60 years or so

Comment: @JonCuster Aha. I'm afraid you've rumbled me there sir. My data was based on a very small sample of employees from Berlin. Truth is , I don't know if it applied throughout Germany, never mind central Europe.

Comment: Also, going unannounced to someone's home was the standard way to contact anybody before telephone was invented and widespread.

Comment: That's a pretty intelligent point. @Pere

Comment: Maybe you should look at how these things were done in Prague, where Kafka was born and lived for most of his life.